# Correlation function of 4-currents on a general QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, tensor-calculus, greens-functions, correlation-functions, poincare-symmetry

Given $V^\mu(x)$ a 4-current of a general unitary, Poincaré invariant QFT, I need to show that the correlation function:
$$iC_{\mu\nu}(x-y) = \langle {\tilde{0}}|T\left[V_\mu(x)V_{\nu}^\dagger(y)\right]|{\tilde{0}}\rangle$$
($|{\tilde{0}}\rangle$ is the vacuum of the theory) can be written as
$$C_{\mu\nu}(x) =A(x)g_{\mu\nu}+\partial_\mu\partial_\nu B(x)$$
where: $A(x) = \int d(m^2) \rho_B(m^2) \Delta_F(x;m)$ and $B(x) = \int d(m^2) \rho_B(m^2) \Delta_F(x;m)$
$\Delta_F(x;m)$ are the Feynmann propagator for a particle of mass $m$.

Basically, I don't know where to start as trying to use that $V_\mu(x) = e^{iPx}V_\mu(0)e^{-iPx}$ and doing some Fourier transforms just gets me to a dead end.